# How to draw the tree diagram for this sentence?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

Here is the sentence "That toy, I think they gave to the dog". Should  "gave to the dog" be considered as VP and "to the dog" as PP?

Comment: All your questions about how to draw tree diagrams are going to be closed.

Comment: @YellowSky May I ask what kind of questions about tree diagram I can ask?

Comment: If you have a problem with a diagram, post your own variant of it, explain why you can't do it, show what sources you consulted and why they don't help you, show your efforts in studying the problem. Such questions are valid here.

Comment: @YellowSky Okay, I see. I'll ask the questions according to this next time. Thank you a lot.

Comment: And you have to explain the exact framework (or sub-framework, be as detailed as you can) you are working under.

Comment: @ronghe I drew the tree without the aid of a drawing tool, hence the jagged lines in the triangles! It's based on the 'standard' schema found in modern descriptive grammar, which I think is more helpful than the myriad ones based on theoretical grammars. Note that the constituents are labelled for category and function, which many people find particularly helpful.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I saw that. It's really kind of you to do this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified tree of your sentence. Note the prenucleus in object function.

Yes, "to the dog" is a PP. and "gave to the dog" is a VP.

[image]